# Сломалась Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль

Разрешил права RWX для системной папки /usr/ система сломалась... Модули Bluetooth и WiFi не работают. Нет кнопки выключения системы (благо у меня ноутбук). Пробовал через

> chmod 740 /usr/

Но всё равно не помогло.
Команду sudo использовать не могу. Резервной копии нет. Помогите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не мучьте себя, делайте бэкап папки /home на внешний диск и переустанавливайте систему. В оконцовке это будет быстрее и без последующих сюрпризов. Когда заново накатите систему, не забудьте поставить TimeShift. Это софтинка с помощью которой вы сможете откатить изменения если еще чего наэксперементируете.

Answer (score 6):

Вероятно, вы попытались рекурсивно выставить права 777 на системный каталог /usr и все его подкаталоги. Это опасная операция, ломающая систему.

Надежным решением этой проблемы можно считать переустановку системы, предварительно скопировав пользовательские данные из папки /home.

В качестве лайтового варианта можно попробовать попросить apt переустановить все имеющиеся пакеты.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall `dpkg -l | awk '/^[hi]i/{print $2}'`
```

Правда, нет гарантий, что это поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть [**pkexec**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html), выполните

```
pkexec chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
pkexec chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

После этого `sudo` будет работать.