# Реинкарнация Ubuntu на новом диске

Tags: ubuntu

На моем лаптопе поломался диск. Раздел с Ubuntu 18.04 уже сохранен на флешку с помощью `ddrescue`.
На новом диске я хочу опять Windows и Ubuntu.  Windows я практически не использую, он мне нужен на случай, что забарахлит какая-то физическая компонента, а в компьютерном магазине скажут "Мы  Ubuntu не понимаем, на Windows, наверно, работает."

Сейчас на новом диске уже установлена  Windows.
У меня есть USB флешка для установки  Ubuntu 16.04 (с которой и запускался `ddrescue`). 
Мне кажется, нет смысла делать флешку для инсталляции 18.04, раз скоро выходит 20.04 и тогда уже я сделаю флешку для нее.

Как мне лучше его восстанавливать все на новом диске?

Можно ли сделать так:

- Ставлю dual boot с Ubuntu 16.0. Раздел с Ubuntu 16.04 должен быть больше или такой же, как раздел с Ubuntu 18.04 на погибшем диске.
- На место Ubuntu 16.04 копирую Ubuntu 18.04 помощью `ddrescue`.

Будет ли это работать, или GRUBу нужно явно сказать, что он будет работать с 18.04?
Альтернатива, которая мне кажется более безопасной, но более длинной:

- Ставлю dual boot с Ubuntu 16.0.
- Обновляю Ubuntu 16.0 до 18.04.
- На место Ubuntu 18.04 копирую Ubuntu 18.04 помощью `ddrescue`.

Или совсем совсем длинный вариант:

- Ставлю dual boot с Ubuntu 16.0.
- Обновляю Ubuntu 16.0 до 18.04.
- Вручную копирую `/home` и все настройки.

Этот вариант лучше тем,  что позволяет разделить Ubuntu на  `/home` и все остальное.

Может, есть лучше варианты?

**UPD:** система с BIOSом и MBR.
После некоторых колебаний я пришла к выводу, что мне таки нужен отдельный раздел с `/home`. А то [всякое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/824771/185618) [бывает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/890266/185618).

Вопросы на этот момент:

- Что лучше использовать для копирования с флешки, `rsync`? `cp`?
- Если запустить `grub-mkconfig` на диске, на котором `grub` никогда не
  работал, он справится?

**UPD2:**
С копированием и GRUBом все получилось.
Но Ubuntu на новом диске не поднимается. Поломалась куча пакетов, очевидно, пока они обновлялись на старом диске.
Собираюсь переустанавливать :(.

Comment: Что-то всё чересчур мудрёно. Всё сводится к созданию корневой ФС любым способом и установке загрузчика, ставить 16.04 здесь вообще ни к чему, все действия можно прямо с флешки проделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для системы с `UEFI` и `ddrescue` образом включающем `/boot`...

1. Ставим винду. Винда при установке создаёт ESP(UEFI раздел Fat32 размером ~100 mb)
2. Загружаемся с флешки, разбиваем оставшуюся часть диска на разделы(`/`, `/home`).
3. Разворачиваем образ `ddrescue` в корень.
4. Монтируем `ESP` раздел в `/boot/efi`
5. Правим `/etc/fstab` и `/etc/default/grub` под текущие реалии.
6. Чрутимся в установленную систему и говорим `sudo grub-mkconfig`
7. Перезагружаемся
8. Profit!

Comment: Как-то у меня есть сомнение насчет того,  что 'ddrescue' сможет при копировании засунуть `/home` в другой раздел. Вы такое пробовали? 
А за 'grub-mkconfig' спасибо, я его сейчас изучаю.

Comment: @user244413 А у вас /home не на отдельном разделе был?

Comment: Увы, вся Ubuntu  в одном разделе была :(

Comment: Тогда разбиваете как я описал, только раздел под /home не монтируете. После того как развернёте из образа, смонтировать раздел под /home куда-нить в /mnt и переместить туда содержимое /home, после чего сам /home удалить. Ну и поредачить /etc/fstab, конечно.

Comment: То есть сначала переписать все в 1 раздел, потом сделать новый раздел и скопировать туда  /home, потом старый  /home удалить и примонтировать новый. И лишь после этого ставить grub, так? Это новый диск, там сейчас только Windows со своим загрузчиком стоит.  BIOSом и MBR. Вопрос, что будет быстрее, копировать с флешки все. и потом копировать  /home еще раз, или сразу с флешки скопировать  /home в свой раздел и  / в свой.

Comment: Вы-ж сказали, что у вас /home и корень в одном образе.

Comment: они не в образе, это просто копия всей структуры директорий. Раздел скопирован в такой же раздел.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103827/discussion-between-oxyd-and-user244413).